# Trying to read/write personal file to databricks user folder

Tags: databricks

I want to save a text file containing passwords to my user folder on databricks .

After saving  a test file to `/Workspace/Users/{username}/file.text`,using thu UI 
[image]

I tried to read it using:

```
%sh
less  `/Workspace/Users/{username}/file.text`
```

got an error:

```
 No such file or directory
```

- What am i dong wrong?
- Is there a better way to save a private file in databricks environmebt?

Comment: Without backticks...?

Answer (score 0):

see [working with files in databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/files/)

Notice, that you should not save passwords in your Workspace for security reasons. Your files would be stored in dbfs which is managed by databricks.
Use Volumes to store your files externally, e.g. in an azure storage.
Or at least use Azure-key-vault-backed secret storage instead. see [secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/databricks/security/secrets/)

Comment: Writing to Workspace File System (WSFS) is supported only since DBR 11.x